# How to set up Vue 3 Firebase project on MacOS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vue-router, vuejs3

I am attempting to set up a VueJS Authentication app using Vue 3 and Firebase on my Mac Mini and Macbook. I have gone through the steps to add Firebase to my VueCLI project, by inputting `npm install firebase` in the terminal after cd-ing to the project. after running `npm install firebase`, Firebase appears as a dependency in package.json. However, after importing firebase and adding the firebaseConfig (from my firebase dashboard) to main.js, as well as importing firebase into App.vue, I get an error in the terminal saying:

```
This dependency was not found:

* firebase in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase
```

This appears to happen only when attempting to run a Vue/Firebase project on MacOS. What is the proper way to install Firebase on a VueCLI project when running that project on MacOS? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Actually, turns out this is NOT a mac issue, but instead an issue with configuring Firebase 9 on on VueCLI 4. The tutorial I was using as a reference for this app hasn't been updated to accommodate Firebase 9. I'll have to go back through the Firebase docs to figure out how to set up Firebase 9 on this project, or in the meantime will use 8.